# Creating a Dictionary from a List of  2-Tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

I have a list of 2-tuples like this:

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

and I want to be able to map this onto a dictionary object, so that I can do something like

```
l.a #=> 1
```

So I tried this, but why does it fail?

```
d = reduce(lambda y,x : y.update({x[0]:x[1]}),l,{})
```

This gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'update'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d['a']
1
```

Comment: Don't know why i didn't figure this out! Thanks Andrey

Comment: While this solves mcnemesis's problem, this answer doesn't address his question as to why his code was failing.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: Because `dict.update` returns `None`, not the dict.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, True the answer doesn't "answer" my problem, but once I realized what I was doing wrong, and after seeing @Andrey's answer, I adopted his "clean" approach.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do this:

```
d = dict(l)
```

Also, to answer your question, your solution is failing because `y` (which is a 2-tuple) has no method update, since it's not a dict. Thankfully, what you're doing is built right in.

Comment: Thanks @Rafe Kettler, what confuses me though about my approach, is; on the first time that `reduce` run, given that I pass in the `{}` as `initial value`, can't I call `update` on it? Isn't `y` bound to the value `{}` in this case, the first time `reduce` executes? Or am I mistaken?